# OAuth 2.0 email address

Tags: coldfusion, oauth

If I do the following:

```
<cflocation url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&client_id=#Application.Google.client_id#&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.PhillipSenn.com%2FLR%2FGoogle%2FCallback&response_type=code" addtoken="no">
```

Then I get the "Allow Access" and "No Thanks" screen correctly.
I then Allow Access, and my callback screen is called correctly.

Q: What do I do now?  I need to ascertain the email address of the user.

The only thing I see is: url.code, which doesn't look usable.
Do I have to then call

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo
```

using something called an access_token?  I don't think so because that's talking about JavaScript, and I'm doing all this server side.  And besides, I don't need the user profile information - I just need their email address.

Edit:

[This link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse) looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That call gives you `access_token` which allows you (for a limited time) access user information. It does not matter where you use it, server side is ok.

Just make sure your request to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo` has `access_token=youraccess_token` as a parameter

Comment: Also note that in some cases ```access_token``` might expire and you'll need to get a new one either by re-acquiring it from user or by using ```refresh_token``` (if one was provided by OAuth provider)

Comment: I don't see access_token anywhere.  I see url.code.  Is that it?

Comment: Could you post a full response? Here's google docs that should be followed: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent

Comment: Should be something like: ```https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/oauthcallback#access_token=1/fFBGRNJru1FQd44AzqT3Zg&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600```

Comment: Does it have to do with me using response_type=code?  Here is the full response:

Comment: `http://www.phillipsenn.com/LR/Google/Callback/?code=4/oB2beeO0V6zbDnox2o_FQWQxxefl.whkLhRtPqjIRshQV0ieZDAo8g8EQeAI`

Comment: In the [Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) they have a 2nd step to exchange authorization code for tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The first time Google redirects, you have to do the following:

```
<form method="post" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token">
    <input name="code" value="#url.code#">
    <input name="client_id" value="#Google.client_id#">
    <input name="client_secret" value="#Google.client_secret#">
    <input name="redirect_uri" value="#Google.redirect_uri#">
    <input name="grant_type" value="authorization_code">
    <input type="submit" name="getAccessToken" value="Get Access Token">
</form>
```

Comment: But if I do that, it simply takes them to the json return code.  I need to perform some sort of chttp command instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like the following:

```
<cfhttp method="post" name="qry" url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="code" value="#url.code#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="client_id" value="#Google.client_id#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="client_secret" value="#Google.client_secret#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="redirect_uri" value="#Google.redirect_uri#">
    <cfhttpparam type="formfield" name="grant_type" value="authorization_code">
</cfhttp>
<cfdump var="#qry#">
```